# Images Lazy load

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

After some googling and a little brainwork i came up with this small script to lazy load my images:

```
function elementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0 && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight));
}
function lazyLoad() {
    var els, backgroundImage;
    els = document.getElementsByClassName('lazyLoad');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        backgroundImage = els[i].dataset.bgimg;
        if (elementInViewport(els[i])) {
            els[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backgroundImage+')';
        };
    };
};
lazyLoad();
window.addEventListener('scroll',lazyLoad);
```

And the html:

```
<div class="lazyLoad" data-bgimg="<?php echo $image_url; ?>"></div>
```

I am wondering if this is actually working because it seems it does: the background image style is correctly applied just when the element appears in view, i checked via dev tools, but it does it so fast that it actually seems that the image was already loaded somewhere, maybe in memory because of the data-bgimg? I also ctrl+shift+r reloaded the page so as not to use the cache but same result: too fast to be real.

Comment: be aware that onscroll can fire hundreds of times a second, and you reset even loaded images...

Comment: Are you testing on localhost? If you do, then the loading will be really fast. First of all disable cache while dev tools is open (there's an option for that). Secondly try using network throttling to slow down the loading speeds.

Comment: thanks @dandavis, didn't think about that. I will later add a condition that checks if the element already has a bg img applied. And if i understood what you mean about the onscroll event i am always a bit frightened about using it, for the same reason you wrote, but a client asked for lazy load and i want to minimize the use of plugins and libraries

Comment: didn't know about network throttling, thanks @Cristy! I am testing in a live server but i just realized that maybe the issue is the fact that the image is always the same...for testing purposes

Comment: As to the point @dandavis made, look into doing a debounce or throttle on the onscroll event. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: debounce seems a must have in this case, will use it, thanks @flybear

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay to your setting of the backgroundImage style. This will enable you to observe the lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use an micro javascript plugin. E.g. a very lightweight one is [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/).

You have the advantage that it's working and you get a well tested code. Maybe you can look into the implementation, because some of your functions/attributes (e.g. dataset) are not supported by older IE browsers. If you need such old browsers ;)